# What is the point of using httpSession object when we already have servlet context object?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

What is the point of using `httpSession` object when we already have a `httpServlet` context object?
The `httpSession` object is limited only to particular user or browser, but the `httpServlet` context object is available to multiple users and multiple browsers.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, as you seem to answer it in your second sentence. Please can you explain more clearly what your issue is?

Comment: You already gave the answer yourself. Use HttpSession when you want to associate data (attributes) only to particular user or browser and use ServletContext when you want to associate data (attribute) to multiple users and browsers. How exactly is this unclear/illogical to you?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go through the documentation.

[HTTPSession](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)

> **public interface HttpSession**
>
> Provides a way to identify a user across more than one page request or
> visit to a Web site and to store information about that user.
>
> The servlet container uses this interface to create a session between an HTTP client and an HTTP server. The session persists for a specified time period, across more than one connection or page request from the user. A session usually corresponds to one user, who may visit a site many times. The server can maintain a session in many ways such as using cookies or rewriting URLs.

[ServletContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)

> **public interface ServletContext**
>
> Defines a set of methods that a servlet uses to communicate with its
> servlet container, for example, to get the MIME type of a file,
> dispatch requests, or write to a log file.
>
> There is one context per "web application" per Java Virtual Machine. (A "web application" is a collection of servlets and content installed under a specific subset of the server's URL namespace such as /catalog and possibly installed via a .war file.)
>
> In the case of a web application marked "distributed" in its deployment descriptor, there will be one context instance for each virtual machine. In this situation, the context cannot be used as a location to share global information (because the information won't be truly global). Use an external resource like a database instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

- Request: you put here elements than only belong to a single request that could be share among servlets and JSP pages - for example result data for a query.
- Session: you put there what has sense for a full session - user id, user name, user privileges, context for a number of related requests, etc.
- ServletContext: you put there what concerns the whole application - number of simultaneous sessions, references for database or third party webservice, etc.

They just have different use cases.